# Removing space which created by "append"

Tags: jquery

There is a table in which unit of measurement is automaticly added to the sizes.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>min</td>
  <td class="sizes">1300x900</td>
  <td class="sizes">1400x900</td>
 </tr>
</table>

$(".sizes").append("грн");
```

The problem in next, when I add the unit of measurement it formes me the space between sizes and units. How to remove the space?

Comment: I don't see any spaces? http://jsfiddle.net/GNpz4/

Comment: Devil in the details, one space destroys my table;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c4vH2/ no spaces, it's probably your styling, or any other html/js

Comment: @MattGibson beat me to it

Comment: then it's php , becouse I get the sizes from editor(wp) 
the class "sizes" look like <td class="sizes"><?$gabarity_vusota = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wptuts_gabarity_vusota', true);echo ' '.$gabarity_vusota;?></td>

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with how its displayed. inspect element on sizes, and see what's causing the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am not seeing any space, This will remove whatever *eveil space* your are seeing

```
$(".sizes").each(function(){
   $(this).text($.trim($(this).text()) + "грн");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4vH2/1/)